# Why can't I use general registers in RISC-V?

Tags: assembly, riscv, platformio

I'm trying to build my project, but there is a problem.

I used PlatformIO IDE, and Freedom E SDK platform.

Here is my code snippet.

```
.global gstest1
.type gstest1, @function
gstest1:
    lw      a2, 4(a0)
    lw      a3, (a0)
    li      a6, 1976782
    macro_one a0, a3, a2, 0, 4, a4, t4, t5, t6, t1, t2, a6
    ...
```

This function has only one argument of array. So `a0` would be the address of array.
And `macro_one` is a macro.

I tried to load the second and first element of array in `a2` and `a3` respectively.

Then I got some errors when I built it.

```
Building in debug mode
Linking .pio\build\hifive1-revb\firmware.elf
c:/users/.platformio/packages/toolchain-riscv/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/8.3.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: .pio\build\hifive1-revb\src\ntt_asm.o: in function `.L0 ':
C:\Users\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\test/src/ntt_asm.S:128: undefined reference to `a3'
c:/users/.platformio/packages/toolchain-riscv/bin/../lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/8.3.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\Documents\PlatformIO\Projects\test/src/ntt_asm.S:128: undefined reference to `a4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\hifive1-revb\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

The error looks like there is no register named `a3` and `a4`.
Also, there might be a label named `.L0`, but I could not find the label anywhere.

Aren't the `a` registers general registers? Why can't I use them?
And what does the label `.L0` means? I didn't declared it anywhere.

Comment: Which line of your code is line 128?  I suspect that the problem is actually in the expansion of `macro_one` - perhaps the parameters that you are passing `a3` and `a4` for are being used in a context where a register name is not meaningful.

Comment: If you have any compiler-generated asm, GCC auto-numbers its code labels `.L0`, `.L1`, etc.  IDK if anything else that auto-generates local (file-scope) label names might use this convention.

Comment: @jasonharper ```a4``` is expanded as ```lw a4, (a0)```, then it is used as operand of addition and subtraction. Is it matter?

Comment: I found that I made a mistake with store operation. ```sw a2, a4``` would not allowed imo.

Comment: Right, your assembler presumably allows `sw reg, symbol` as a pseudo-instruction, so it was looking at `a4` as a symbol name, since it wasn't inside `()` it assumed it wasn't a register.